# Synchronization between server instances with static discovery and shared storage setup

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have created the Apache Artemis server instance HA cluster setup with static discovery and shared storage mode. I have created master server setup in one machine and slave setup in second machine. I have created new queue say `queue.xyz` in master server. I opened management console in slave server but queue details is not present.

I am wondering why queue presence is not visible to second machine even though I used shared storage mode configuration. My assumption here is, shared storage mode is synchronizing all the queues and topic details in all two servers. Please let me know if i am wrong in my assumption.

Can anybody have any clue and guide me where I have missed something in this setup.

Here's the master's `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

      <bindings-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/journal</journal-directory>
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

      <large-messages-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

      <paging-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/paging</paging-directory>

      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

     <ha-policy>
        <shared-store>
            <master>

                <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
                <wait-for-activation>true</wait-for-activation>

            </master>
        </shared-store>
    </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://192.168.1.1:61616</connector>
         <connector name="netty-backup-connector">tcp://192.168.1.2:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <!-- Acceptors -->
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://192.168.1.1:61616</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>netty-backup-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      <!-- Other config -->


      <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

      <security-settings>
         <!--security for example queue-->
         <security-setting match="exampleQueue">
            <permission roles="guest" type="createDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="consume"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="send"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Here's the slave's `broker.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">
   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">

      <bindings-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/bindings</bindings-directory>

      <journal-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/journal</journal-directory>
      <journal-type>NIO</journal-type>
      <journal-max-io>1</journal-max-io>

      <large-messages-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/largemessages</large-messages-directory>

      <paging-directory>/home/Apache/shareddrive/ApacheArtemis/data/paging</paging-directory>

      <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>

      <cluster-password>admin</cluster-password>

      <ha-policy>
          <shared-store>
              <slave>
                  <allow-failback>true</allow-failback>
                  <failover-on-shutdown>true</failover-on-shutdown>
               </slave>
          </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>

      <connectors>
         <connector name="netty-connector">tcp://192.168.1.2:61616</connector>
         <connector name="netty-backup-connector">tcp://192.168.1.1:61616</connector>
      </connectors>

      <!-- Acceptors -->
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://192.168.1.2:61616</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <cluster-connections>
         <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
            <connector-ref>netty-connector</connector-ref>
            <static-connectors>
               <connector-ref>netty-backup-connector</connector-ref>
            </static-connectors>
         </cluster-connection>
      </cluster-connections>
      <!-- Other config -->


      <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

      <security-settings>
         <!--security for example queue-->
         <security-setting match="exampleQueue">
            <permission roles="guest" type="createDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="consume"/>
            <permission roles="guest" type="send"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="exampleQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="exampleQueue"/>
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have created master server setup in one machine and slave setup in second machine using static discovery with shared storage mode. I have created new queue say queue.xyz in master server. I opened management console in slave server but queue details is not present. My assumption here is, shared storage mode is synchronizing all the queues and topic details in all two servers. Please let me know if i am wrong in my assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is expected.

In an ActiveMQ Artemis HA pair (i.e. a master & slave) one broker will be *active* and one broker will be *passive*. If you look at the management console of the active broker you'll see all the normal runtime data (e.g. addresses, queues, message counts, connection counts, etc.). However, if you look at the management console of the passive broker you'll see very little because the broker is passive. It has not loaded any of the message data (since it's not active). It doesn't have any client connections, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I will check slave broker instance behaviour post master broker stopped status using management console.